# Twitter Search Widget - Not pulling tweets chronologically

Tags: twitter

I have an issue whereby the twitter widget is not pulling tweets in the right order. It might pull a tweet 6 hours ago and then another 2 mins ago and then another 5 hours ago which is quite frustrating.

Does anybody know what would cause this? and how to get the widget to pull tweets in the correct order?

thanks

BIOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search can return tweets based on their popularity.

Add this to your query

```
result_type=recent
```

See the [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search).

Comment: Thanks Terence. I'm actually using a widget so would have to make the js code local I guess and edit from there.